# How can I prevent the documentation/signature popup from appearing in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

The following documentation notification is a distraction, it appears whenever I type `ejs.render()`.

How can I disable it?

[image: Typing "ejs.render()" will always come up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `"editor.parameterHints": false` in your user configuration.